# Is there a way to change default include paths of projects in VisualStudio?

Tags: visual-studio, solution

So I am programming using Visual Studio. I have one solution and many projects in that solution. Each time I want to create a new project I had to manually change the include and lib path, and this seems very inconvenient.

I tried tinkering around with solution properties but didn't find anything.

Could someone tell me if I am on the right track? If not, what should I do? I thank you in advance!

Comment: See [Share or reuse Visual Studio project settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/create-reusable-property-configurations?view=msvc-160) and/or [Directory.Build.props and Directory.Build.targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019#directorybuildprops-and-directorybuildtargets).